# multipart/form-data binding for ModelAttribute fails if multipart file param is null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, recaptcha, thymeleaf

I have a controller mapped for processing uploaded files

**Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/careers/pursue", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Callable<String> pursue(
      final @RequestParam("g-recaptcha-response") String captchaResponse,
      final @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
      final @ModelAttribute("jobapplication") @Valid JobApplication application, final BindingResult bindingResult,
      final Model model)
```

**form**

```
<form name="jobsForm" id="jobsForm" novalidate="novalidate" action="#" th:action="@{/careers/pursue}"
                    th:object="${jobapplication}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>                    
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" th:field="*{phone}" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Email Address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" th:field="*{email}" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address."/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Role:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="role" th:field="*{role}" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address."/>
        </div>
    </div>                    
    <div class=" control-group form-group">
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"></div>                    
    </div>
    <div class=" control-group form-group">
         <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                Add your Resumé <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required="required"/>
                         </span>
    </div>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Apply!</button>
</form>
```

Now, if a person misses attaching a file to the form before submit,

```
-----------------------------749526091303082321866336941
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"

Anadi
-----------------------------749526091303082321866336941
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"

Misra
-----------------------------749526091303082321866336941
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"

9845420420
-----------------------------749526091303082321866336941
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

foo@bar.com
-----------------------------749526091303082321866336941
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="role"

open.project
-----------------------------749526091303082321866336941
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="g-recaptcha-response"

03AHJ_Vuv9i7WQ_4zCipfnyrLNl6467l_cZgGIhkdpLjS1M0YmWvwQMOWQeRcrAHFh8s3-jO13NQs7019lzI7UobwNeHKIhBmcLMiVGPk38Iy8BjrEi2glI4QGjE4VTvRhV_-WWYsmlzV_7PRPE5Y8L0NboPXYoG9JSabMOL8V958w74pOzkxabsoR4wouCSa0gzo0EbOsLiCWjd0MAvZiCcKJGdwIlMp0WIjxcufB-RfG2F0rwv65yrgL-By0bdMewkWULY_aRvC-FRSqOEM9X5Qg4gviA-cvc5IY2XnRtaUALOPlR_QbwjgUKl2mJEFNab6Pks3MlsivuEZFkba4isDFlrJ4jXwBBQ
-----------------------------749526091303082321866336941
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------749526091303082321866336941--
```

or tries to submit without validating captcha, I get this exception

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (jobs:91)
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'jobapplication' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:396)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:323)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:289)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:98)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
... 66 common frames omitted
```

What I expect is that I get empty values for captcha response and file and then my controller method should be able handle it, and send user back to the form with specific error message. It works like so on forms without multipart data, i.e. I  do not get binding errors but null values in the controller arguments. I see this issue only when I use **Multipart Form data**, the binding goes all fine if all the data is populated, i.e. a user verifies captcha, and attaches a file.

Making these params optional or using RequestPart hasn't also helped (I admit I really do not get what is the purpose of `RequestPart`annotation) So, changing the controller to this (knee jerk experimentations ;-))

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/careers/pursue", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Callable<String> pursue(
      final @RequestPart(value = "g-recaptcha-response", required = false) String captchaResponse,
      final @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
      final @ModelAttribute("jobapplication") @Valid JobApplication application, final BindingResult bindingResult,
      final Model model)
```

does not help either. Do I have to extend [StandardServletMultipartResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardServletMultipartResolver.html) or is it something to change/fix in [SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring3/1.0.1/org/thymeleaf/spring3/processor/attr/SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor.html), or am I missing some minor detail here?

***Update***

Adding Controller method

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/careers/pursue", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Callable<String> pursue(final @ModelAttribute("jobapplication") @Valid JobApplication application,
      final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model,
      final @RequestParam(value = "g-recaptcha-response", required = false) String captchaResponse,
      final @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    return new Callable<String>() {
      @Override
      public String call() throws Exception {
        try {
          model.asMap().clear();
          GoogleCaptchaResponseData response = captchaVerifier.isCaptchaResponseValid(captchaResponse).get();
          model.addAttribute("recaptcha", response.isSuccess());
          model.addAttribute("recaptchamessage", response.getErrorCodes());

          if (response.isSuccess() && !file.isEmpty()) {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            LOGGER.info("Found file of type {}", file.getOriginalFilename());
            ByteArrayInputStream inputBytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            mailApi.sendMail(mailApi.buildJobApplicationEmail(application, new BufferedInputStream(inputBytes)));
            model.asMap().clear();
            model.addAttribute("uploadsuccess", true);
            model.addAttribute("resource_host", resourceHost);
            model.addAttribute("jobapplication", new JobApplication());
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
          LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
          model.asMap().clear();
          model.addAttribute("jobapplication", application);
          model.addAttribute("resource_host", resourceHost);
          model.addAttribute("uploadsuccess", false);
        }
        return "jobs";
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

@RequestPart relies on HttpMessageConvertors and content-type to bind the multipart data to method param, whereas @RequestParam relies on registered convertors to do the conversion. Spring mvc provides certain convertors by default. You can use either @RequestParam or @RequestPart to bind the file data. Most of the applications use commons file upload for uploading file and register

> org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver

for multi part resolving. When this is registered, spring check every request for multi part data and use it to resolve this to method arg. check here

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

There are couple of items you can try. Make sure both of your captcha and file params are optional like below in your controller. I switched to @RequestParam for captcha.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/careers/pursue", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Callable<String> pursue(
      final @RequestParam(value = "g-recaptcha-response", required = false) String captchaResponse,
      final @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
      final @ModelAttribute("jobapplication") @Valid JobApplication application, final BindingResult bindingResult,
      final Model model)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the `StandardServletMultipartResolver` behave any different from `CommonsMultipartResolver` ?

Comment: it can help as well. It is configured  differently. I mostly used commons. What are you using?

Comment: I am on spring boot which apparently uses `StandardServletMultipartResolver` as default multipart resolver.

Comment: changed to the syntax suggested by @minion and added configuration for `CommonsMultipartResolver`, hasn't helped, still get the same error

Comment: I tried in Spring boot a sample app, but without google captcha though. It works fine. If you are using spring-boot, then you don't need CommonsMultipartResolver. Can you post your complete controller. It looks like there is something missing which i could not figure out with the info provided. Thanks.

Comment: I saw the documentation for multi part again and I couldn't see any difference that  `CommonsMultipartResolver` would bring over the standard servlet multi part resolver.  Adding Controller code in a short while.

Comment: added controller method

Comment: What is the version of spring-boot you are using? Would you mind updating the post with it. It works fine in my sample app. So trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72635/discussion-between-anadi-misra-and-minion).

Comment: @minion I am having the same issue. Please let me know if you guys found any workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your Controller `@RequestMapping` isn't mapped to the same path as for form
2. In your form make sure your input name for the file and captcha match the `@RequestParam`
3. `@RequestParam` doesn't pass a null notice I'm looking for `length() == 0` and `file.isEmpty()`

Also you may want to take a look at the [spring guide for file upload](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String pursue(
            final @RequestParam("g-recaptcha-response") String captchaResponse,
            final @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            final @ModelAttribute("jobapplication") @Valid JobApplication application, final BindingResult bindingResult,
            final Model model)
    {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors() || captchaResponse.length() == 0 || file.isEmpty())
        {
            return "form";
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

**Form**

```
<form name="jobsForm" id="jobsForm" novalidate="novalidate" action="#" th:action="@{/upload}"
      th:object="${jobapplication}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span>First Name: </span>
    <input id="firstname" th:field="*{firstName}" type="text"/><br/>
    <span>Last Name: </span>
    <input id="lastname" th:field="*{lastName}" type="text"/><br/>
    <span>Phone: </span>
    <input id="phone" th:field="*{phone}" type="text"/><br/>
    <span>Email: </span>
    <input id="email" th:field="*{email}" type="text"/><br/>
    <span>Role: </span>
    <input id="role" th:field="*{role}" type="text"/><br/>
    <span></span>
    <input type="text" name="g-recaptcha-response"/><br/>
    <span>File: </span>
    <input type="file" name="file"/><br/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do I get the exception even before controller method can be executed if any of the params is empty? The form action url was not a problem, I forgot to update it when I had edited the question

Comment: The error that you posted is about the jobapplication bean instead of the file. Is jobapplication  bean null? Is the captcha and file part of jobapplication ?

Comment: if you look at the multipart data I posted, I get this error for `jobapplication` bean if either `file` or `g-response-captcha` is empty. That is baffling me. captcha param is attached to the request by google captcha, file and captcha are not a part of the `jobapplication` bean

Comment: @AnadiMisra I have file as part of bean.  'modelattribute' mapping fails when I try to submit the form without selecting file. Did you find any solution?